# System Lags/Freezes when under high usage

Tags: memory, performance, gpu

I am not sure if its my GPU / Memory or Hard drive thats failing. For example if I'm running more than one instance of chrome and running an application that takes up a lot of resources, my system will start to lag and freeze. When I launch Photoshop the GPU feature disables automatically, this also lags when I click on menus and when working on documents in Photoshop. I really dont know where to start, if i should buy a new graphics card or test the memory or could it be my OS drive?

System: Windows 7 64bit, ATI Raedeon 5850, Corsair 2x4GB

Here is a screenshot of the TaskManager:

[image]

Comment: I'd suspect heat, particularly CPU overheating.

Comment: Is it worth reseating the cpu and cooler? or will i have to get it replaced

Comment: your Windows runs out of RAM. TaskMgr shows only that 4GB is used. Make sure you don't limit the RAM to 4GB with msconfig.exe.

Answer (score 0):

I believe overheating is the cause of your problem. Depending on how long this have been happening your hardware could have suffered unrepairable damage. You should try cleaning your computer fans and vents.

Comment: The fans are clean

Comment: I have now cleaned all vents and fans. http://i.stack.imgur.com/qqkLZ.jpg But it is still unresponsive and lags a lot during window switching like when i have two chrome browsers open on dual monitors. Could this be a memory issue?

Comment: Check this out. Its weird that your memory comsumption is really high. Follow this steps to rule out problems: http://superuser.com/a/132539/143188